# Power BI - Sorting the Column Series by date order in Line and Stacked Column chart

Tags: powerbi

I have a chart where the date format needs to be mmm-yy with the dates ordered by month.

Power BI does not have the desired date format so I created a new column to format the date as mmm-yy but this stores as text in the model which means the dates are ordered alphabetically. I tried adding an index to the date column to sort the date by month, this orders the data in the data section, but in the chart the dates are still ordered alphabetically.

Comment: Use [Sort by column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-sort-by-column). If you gives us more information about your model, you could get more detailed instructions what to do.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention I already did that, it sorts the column in the data model, but in the chart the month axis is still ordered alphabetically...